# Five figures summary with dbplyr

Tags: r, impala, summary, dbplyr

I have 4 years experience using R but I am very new to the Big Data game as I always worked on csv files.

It is thrilling to manipulate large amount of data from a distance but also somehow frustating as simple things you were used to are to be rengineered.

The task I am struggling right now is to have a basic 5 figure summary of a variable:

```
summary(df$X)
```

Some context, I am connected with impala, these lines of codes work fine:

```
library(dbplyr)
localTable <- tbl(con, 'serverTable')
localTable %>% tally()
localTable %>% filter(X > 10) %>% tally()
```

If I just write

```
localTable
```

instead, RStudio gets stuck/takes a lot of time so I suppress it with the task manager.

Coming back to my current question, I tried to have a 5 figure summary in these ways:

```
summary(localTable$X) #returns Length 0, Class NULL, Mode NULL
localTable %>% fivenum(X) #returns Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'
```

also building a custom summary() with summarise

```
localTable %>% summarize(Min = min(X),
         Q1 = quantile(X, .25),
         Avg = mean(X), 
         Q3 = quantile(X, .75),
         Max = max(X))
```

returns me a SYNTAX ERROR.

My guess is that there is a very trivial missing link between my code and the server in form of a data structure, but I can't figure it out what.

I tried as well to save localTable$x to a in-memory variable with

```
XL <- localTable$X
```

but I always get a NULL

On the graphical side, using dbplot, if I try

```
library(dbplot)
localTable %>% dbplot_histogram(X)
```

I get an empty graphic.

I thought about leveraging the 5 figures summary in the boxplot function, ggplotbuild(object)$data likewise so to speak, but with dbplot_boxplot I get the error could not find function "dbplot_boxplot".

I started using dbplyr as I am quite fluent with dplyr and I don't want to write queries in SQL with DBI::dbGetQuery, but you can suggest other packages like implyR, sparklyR or the such, as well as tutorials on the subject as large, as the ones I found are quite basic.

EDIT:

as requested in a comment, I add the result of

```
str(localTable)
```

which is

```
    List of 2 
$ src:List of 2
      ..$ con  :Formal class 'Impala' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
      .. .. ..@ ptr     :<externalptr> 
      .. .. ..@ quote   : chr "`"
      .. .. ..@ info    :List of 15
      .. .. .. ..$ dbname                       : chr "IMPALA"
      .. .. .. ..$ dbms.name                    : chr "Impala"
      .. .. .. ..$ db.version                   : chr "2.9.0-cdh5.12.1"
      .. .. .. ..$ username                     : chr "User"
      .. .. .. ..$ host                         : chr ""
      .. .. .. ..$ port                         : chr ""
      .. .. .. ..$ sourcename                   : chr "impala connector"
      .. .. .. ..$ servername                   : chr "Impala"
      .. .. .. ..$ drivername                   : chr "Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala"
      .. .. .. ..$ odbc.version                 : chr "03.80.0000"
      .. .. .. ..$ driver.version               : chr "2.6.11.1011"
      .. .. .. ..$ odbcdriver.version           : chr "03.80"
      .. .. .. ..$ supports.transactions        : logi FALSE
      .. .. .. ..$ getdata.extensions.any_column: logi TRUE
      .. .. .. ..$ getdata.extensions.any_order : logi TRUE
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "Impala" "driver_info" "list"
      .. .. ..@ encoding: chr ""
      ..$ disco: NULL
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:4] "src_Impala" "src_dbi" "src_sql" "src"
     $ ops:List of 2
      ..$ x   : 'ident' chr "serverTable"
      ..$ vars: chr [1:157] "X" ...
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "op_base_remote" "op_base" "op"
     - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:5] "tbl_Impala" "tbl_dbi" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" ...
```

Not sure if I can dput my table as it is sensitive information

Comment: Hi @goingdeep, looks like the query isn't returning any results based on the ```Length 0,``` in your ```summary```? I'm guessing you are not  able to run ```str(localTable)``` either?

Comment: hello `str(localTable)` outputs a List of 2, the same I see in the Environment tab in RStudio if I expand it

Comment: Can you add the results of ```str(localTable)``` in your question? Also might be helpful to show ```dput(head(localTable,10))``` in the question to provide a sample of the first ten rows of data?

Comment: I add that `localTable %>% summarize(mean = mean(x))` works fine (it doesn't though with `na.rm = TRUE`)

Comment: So which sub-list are you accessing? Based on the ```str``` output, I don't understand how ```localTable %>% summarize(mean = mean(x))``` is giving any output as ```localTable$x``` isn't a variable?  Also, you reference ```X``` and ```x``` in your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few aspects to your post. I am going to try and address the main ones.

**(1)** What you are calling `localTable` is not local. What you have is a local access point to a remote table. It is a remote table because the data is stored in the database, rather than in R.

To copy a remote table into local R memory use `localTable = collect(remoteTable)`. Use this carefully. If the table is many GB in the database this will be slow to transfer into R. Also if you `collect` a database table that is bigger than the ram avaialble to R then you will receive an out of memory error.

I recommend using `collect` for moving summary results into R. Do the processing and summarizing in the database and just fetch the results into R. Alternatively, use `remoteTable %>% head(20) %>% collect()` to copy just the first 20 rows into R.

**(2)** The `tableName$colname` will not work for remote tables. In R the `$` notation lets you access a named component of a list. Data.frames are a special kind of list. If you try `data(iris)` followed by `names(iris)` you will get the columns names of iris. Any of these can be accessed using `iris$`.

However as your `str(localTable)` shows, `localTable` is a list of length 2 with the first named item `src`. If you call `names(localTable)` then you will receive two names back, the first of which is `src`. This means you can call `localTable$src` (and as `localTable$src` is also a list you can also call `localTable$src$con`).

When working with dbplyr R translates data manipulation commands into the database language. There are translations defined for most dplyr commands, but there are not translations defined for all R commands.

So the recommended approach to access just a specific column is using `select` from dplyr:

```r
local_copy_of_just_one_column = remoteTable %>%
  select(required_column) %>%
  collect()
```

**(3)** You have the right approach with a custom summary function. This is the best approach for producing the five figure summary without pulling the data into local memory (RAM).

One possible cause of the syntax error is that you may have used R commands that do not have a translation into your database language.

You can check whether a command has translations defined using `translate_sql`. I recommend you try

```r
library(dbplyr)
translate_sql(quantile(colname, 0.25))
```

To see what the translation look like.

You can view the translation of an entire table manipulation using `show_query`. This is my go-to approach when debugging SQL translation. Try:

```r
localTable %>%
  summarize(Min = min(X),
            Q1 = quantile(X, .25),
            Avg = mean(X), 
            Q3 = quantile(X, .75),
            Max = max(X)) %>%
  show_query()
```

If this does not produce valid SQL then executing the command will error.

One possible cause is the `Min` and `Max` have special meanings in SQL and so might produce odd behavior in your translation.

When I experimented with `quantile` it looks like it might need an `OVER` clause in SQL. This is created using `group_by`. So perhaps you want something like the following:

```r
localSummary = remoteTable %>%
  # create dummy column
  mutate(ones = 1) %>%
  # group to satisfy over clause
  group_by(ones) %>%
  summarise(var_min = min(var),
            var_lq = quantile(var, 0.25),
            var_mean = mean(var),
            var_uq = quantile(var, 0.75),
            var_max = max(var)) %>%
  # copy results from database into R memory
  collect()
```

Comment: Thank you Simon for the detailed and thorough answer.

Comment: - the table I need is only 1.5GB, I copied it locally in case I can't extract the infos I want from remote
- with `remoteTable %>% head(20) %>% collect()` I get the error `Error while retrieving data from in Impala: [08S01] : ImpalaThriftAPICallFailed `. I am investigating it, but it seems something for the IT department. I get a similar error with `remoteTable`.

Comment: - `local_copy_of_just_one_column = remoteTable %>%
  select(required_column) %>%
  collect()` I had to abort RStudio as after one hour it was still running. collecting the all table instead took 45 minutes but it got the job done
- your code for the summary doesn' work either, I get `SYNTAX ERROR Encountered: GROUP
Expected: FROM, LIMIT, ORDER, UNION, COMMA`
Anyway I got the gist of it, as that we can't unfortunately forget about SQL when using dbplyr as I hoped